# GitLab CI Pipeline Stage Timeout

Tags: timeout, gitlab-ci

I'm using a self-hosted `GitLab CI server` (community edition v8.9.5) and `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` 1.2.0 to build a project.  One of my pipeline stages (test) takes a while to run and I get the following erm:

> ```
> ERROR: Build failed: execution took longer than 3600 seconds
> ```

Where do I put the override for this timeout?  Can I apply it to just the test pipeline stage?

Answer (score 129):

You can set a global timeout in *Project* → *Settings* → *CI/CD* → *General Pipelines* → *Timeout* **or** *Project* → *Settings* → *Builds* → *Timeout* in older versions.

[image: GitLab 15.1 Timeout]

As of version 12.3, you can set a timeout per stage in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file using [`timeout`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#timeout):

> `timeout` allows you to configure a timeout for a specific job. For example:

```
build:
  script: build.sh
  timeout: 3 hours 30 minutes

test:
  script: rspec
  timeout: 3h 30m
```

> The job-level timeout can exceed the project-level timeout but can’t exceed the Runner-specific timeout.

Comment: At least as of 8.11.5, this setting can be found in **Project settings -> CI/CD Pipeline -> Timeout**

Comment: Can you set the timeout while running the gitlab-runner locally?

Comment: @damian I'd say that it's irrelevant where the runner is running but don't take my word for this.

Comment: [Issue for per job timeouts](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18183)

Answer (score 27):

There are two timeout can be set: **project timeout** and **runner timeout**.

**Project timeout:**

It is possible to set timeout per job from **Settings** -> **CI/CD** -> **General pipelines**

[image]

**Runner timeout:**

runner's timeout can be set from  **Settings** -> **CI/CD** -> **Runners**, select the runner from **Runners activated for this project** and edit the *Maximum job timeout* from the runner edit form. 
[image]

Be aware that these two types of timeout can be overridden by each other. Refer the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#setting-maximum-job-timeout-for-a-runner).

Comment: I get the this error if i run it locally. `ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 30m0s seconds FATAL: execution took longer than 30m0s seconds` . I have alreaddy set the timwout of 1 hour in toml file. Let me know what could be the issue

Comment: Maybe check both project timeout and runner timeout? @shaktisinghmoyal

Comment: I tried out both project timeout and runner timeout. But there were many limitation from gitlab side when running it locally.  the solution which worked out for me is if you are running locally pass the runner timeout with parameters like this with command `gitlab-runner exec docker job_name --timeout 3600`

Comment: Note that if you set the general and runner timeouts, the *smaller* of the two values applies: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#set-maximum-job-timeout-for-a-runner

Answer (score 18):

A job-specific timeout was introduced in Gitlab 12.3

https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#timeout

```
build:
  script: build.sh
  timeout: 3 hours 30 minutes

test:
  script: rspec
  timeout: 3h 30m
```

Comment: I get this error if i run it locally. `ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 30m0s seconds
FATAL: execution took longer than 30m0s seconds` .      I have alreaddy set the timwout of 1 hour in toml file. Let me know what could be the issue

Comment: @shaktisinghmoyal I imagine you've already figured out by now, but there is also a project max timeout and a gitlab runner max timeout that need to be configured by the gitlab admins.

Comment: Does this timeout take into account queuing job for the job? Like if the job is queued for 1 minute, and the timeout is 10 minutes, does the job still have 10 minutes to run once it starts?

Answer (score 3):

If running it at Gitlab, then the above stated answers has already told the right way. But if you would like to run the Gitlab CI locally that too with tour own runner, then runners timeout you need to pass with command.

gitlab-runner exec docker job_name --timeout 3600

here it is setting runners timeout as 3600 seconds

Comment: Is that a command you would run on the runner itself?