# GitLab: Job do not return after script is executed, instead fail by timeout after 1 hour

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

In my .gitlab-ci.yml i have the following job:

```
init_db:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd database-migration
    - "mvn clean install exec:java"
```

The database-migration gets executed. The code for it looks like this:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    doSomeMigration();
    System.out.println("Migration done!");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

In the log from GitLab I get this at the end:

```
Migration done!
ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 1h0m0s seconds
```

So to me it seems like the script ran ok, but after that the job does not end. Can you see what I am doing wrong?

**Edit**

The pom.xml for database-migration looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.domain</groupId>
  <artifactId>database-migration</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
              <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.4.0</version>
              <configuration>
                <executable>java</executable>
                <mainClass>com.domain.DatabaseMigrationApp</mainClass>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
       ... database dependency...
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: All seems correct. Apparently, runner is not picking up the return value from your java code. Seems that you might wanna make sure that **mvn** is returning the correct value. Check if perhaps your poms **successCode** points to an invalid value (if you have one)

Comment: I tested to add ```successCode '0'``` to my configuration without any luck. Added my pom to the question if it can help you help me.

Comment: Firstly, can you lose the quotes from  **"mvn clean install exec:java"**, just so we're sure its not doing anything funny?

Comment: I tried without them as well. In the GitLab documentation I found this: ```commands that contain a colon (:) need to be wrapped in quotes so that the YAML parser knows to interpret the whole thing as a string rather than a "key: value" pair.```, so that is why I added the quotes in the first place.

Comment: Can you try adding  **--batch-mode** to your mvn command

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--batch-mode` to your mvn CLI options

Comment: No luck with that addition.

Comment: This might be an issue with your current Gitlab setup. Can you verify that any maven command will terminate in your console? Like `mvn -v`

Comment: Ok, so **exec-maven-plugin** is missing something. Could you try adding                                                                                    
       `<executions>
          <execution>      <id>my-execution</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>`

Comment: Also, there is a strong chance that `System.exit(0)` will interfere with mvn console, so I would lose that as well.

Comment: I added it within exec-maven-plugin. The job still hangs. (Thanks for helping).

Comment: Also, could you try executing just by using `mvn -B exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.domain.DatabaseMigrationApp"`

Comment: Removed ```System.exit(0)``` but the problem remains. When using ```mvn -B exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.domain.DatabaseMigrationApp"``` I get an error saying ```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.domain.DatabaseMigrationApp```, but the same command works locally.

Comment: When I removed ```System.exit(0)``` the maven command do not retun to my console on my local machine either.

Comment: I created the same scenario and ran it on my setup. Worked just fine. One difference though, my runners use Powershell for shell.

Comment: You are running gitlab-runner on your local machine?

Comment: Indeed I am. Its on a dedicated build server, but its on-prem nonetheless.

Comment: The quest continues. I will try to create the same scenario with as simple implementation as possible to see if I get the same error. Thanks again for your effort, I very much appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Even if your task is successfull, it has timed out, so you have to increase your timeout limit.

See the following existing Stackoverflow question 
[GitLab CI Pipeline Stage Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403681/gitlab-ci-pipeline-stage-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

if you use service `docker:dind`, let's try `docker:19.03.5-dind`. please find details [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/6697).