# Disable jobs marked as failed if stuck for specific Gitlab runners

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

We have one Gitlab runner, which is intended for bench-marking purposes.
A job can take from few minutes to possibly few days.
This all works fine, until there are two jobs and one takes too long to complete.

The waiting job, after some time, complains that it is stuck.
Afterwards it is marked as failed, never to be executed at all.
This is very annoying. For our usual pipeline it makes sense, because either the runner is dead, or the job's `.gitlab.ci` is not set up properly.
However here the waiting job just has to wait more.

Can we disable this stuck->failed feature for this specific runner?

(The timeout of the job is set up correctly, so it is able to run that long, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38403681/gitlab-ci-pipeline-stage-timeout#38403908))

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open issue (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19294).

Comment: In the meantime, you could increase the `concurrent` setting in `config.toml` to allow your pending job to run in parallel. See https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-global-section   For example, you could set `concurrent` to `2`.   I'm offering that as a possible workaround -- you did write you have one GitLab runner intended for bench-marking, so I'm not sure if this is a viable option for you.

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but for benchmarking purposes, this does not make much sense. You need to ensure, that the benchmark is reproducible. If another benchmark is running in parallel, you can't be certain that the numbers are even remotely correct.

This is also not ideal for heavy C++ compilations, since the RAM will run out (depending on the machine of course. Lot of cores, little RAM leads to problems). We use `concurrent` setting on few "strong" servers. One runner is an usual runner, the other one is responsible for building docker images, which does not happen that often.

Comment: Of course. I was afraid that might be the case. Thank you.